# Where are logs of docker nginx conainter stored in host

Tags: docker, nginx, elastic-stack, filebeat

I use [default nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) and Filebeat to read logs and send them to ELK.
Both containers (nginx container and Filebeat container) are on the same host machone.

Here is Dockerfile for nginx image

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

In my nginx container access log goes to `STDOUT` and error log goes to `STDERR`.

When I prompt from host machine `docker logs <nginx-containter-id>` I can see logs from nginx container. 
But there is nothing in container's folder on host machine (`/var/lib/docker/containers/nginx-container-id`)

how can set up filebeat to read logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each container has it's own logfile, you can know where it is by using:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <nginx-containter-id>
```

It will tell you the path to the logfile.

Referencies:

- https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/
- https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#configure-the-default-logging-driver

Comment: I'm afraid there must be something it is not well understood or there are some gap since this command promts the path of the logfile that stores all the output from the container since it was started. It may be a silly question but have you properly set the container id that corresponds to the container?.

If nothing is shown it may be because the docker log system is setted to none like:

docker run -it --log-driver none  <DOCKER_IMAGE>

Comment: Thank you, @LucasPC ! Your last comment and links you provided were helpful. After running container with logging argument, the command shows me the path